# How to add select in leftJoin('questions', function($q) use ($user)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, controller

I have a query like this

```
     $users = User::leftJoin('questions', function($q) use ($user)
    {
        $q->on('users.id', '=', 'questions.user_id')
            ->where('questions.evaluator_id', '=', $user);
    })
    ->where('users.id','!=',auth()->user()->id)
    ->paginate(10);
```

it is working but, I want to add select(users.name as u_name) to get specific column.

I tried this but not working

```
         $users = DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.name as u_name')
        ->('questions', function($q) use ($user)
        {
            $q->on('users.id', '=', 'questions.user_id')
                ->where('questions.evaluator_id', '=', $user);
        })
        ->where('users.id','!=',auth()->user()->id)
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: whats error? may be you would  ->select('users.id , users.name as u_name')

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

> $users = User::select('users.name as u_name')
> ->leftJoin('questions', 'users.id', '=', 'questions.user_id')
> ->where('questions.evaluator_id', '=', $user)
> ->where('users.id','!=',auth()->user()->id)->paginate(10);